# Update elements only if element has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project that is being built around SignalR then JavaScript appending the data to elements.

```
$("#" + div).html(html);
```

The problem I am having is that I am calling the server every 2 seconds

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    chat.server.send("0", 1);

    setInterval(function () {
        chat.server.send("0", 1);
    }, 2000);
});
```

This means it's then updating every div, every time the server returns the data, I have been looking for a way to get JavaScript to handle only updating elements if the data returned has changed, there were two ways I was going to go about doing this.

1. Get the HTML content from the div and do a comparison, however that was flawed because different browsers return different HTML, so that's a no
2. The second way was to store the content in a global variable and when it runs again, compare the global against the current, if it's different update

However I am looking at possibly something built into JavaScript which could handle this for me, currently I am using .html but when looking into this more, I found out that it first does .empty() and re-appended the data and I'm looking for something that'll only update if it's different.

-- EDIT --

How the project is currently setup is that I have a class containing different properties of what needs to be displayed, e.g.

```
public class MyClass {
    public List<DivOneContent> Content1;
    public List<DivTwoContent> Content2;
}
```

On the server side I have it fetch the content and populate the class

```
public void Send(string tab, string subTab = null)
{
    MyClass data = PrepareModel(tab, subTab);
    Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).broadcastObject(data);
}
```

When this is this is turned back to the client side, I have JavaScript functions which take one of the properties and appends that as needed

```
// First param is the content and the second one is the div ID
devious.htmlStringBuilder.buildContentOne(data.Content1, "Content1");
```

In the function I just loop and build a string and append such string to the div using .html

Comment: You could probably build something around passing an MD5 hash of the content alongsides with the content, and store that for later comparison, but I don't see why you're calling the chat server at an interval. Isn't the main idea of SignalR to avoid such polling? And the code surrounding your `$('#'+div).html(html)` will probably be relevant to a good answer here. You're saying it's updating every div, while you seem to be accessing div's by ID.

Comment: I don't know any tool that would do that, but i can propose you an optimisation if you finally want to go for the second solution.

you shouldn't be saving the content it self, but a signature of it. For exemple a Hash of that content, then when you receive data from your server, you send back the hash of the new content. Then you compare Hash. It will be more efficient thant comparing the entire content.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds a bit sloppy, can you give us an example of the response? Why would it return redundant info in the first place? I would check if the content is different in the backend and just have it return the new content that way you always know that it's new.

Comment: You should not interval anything, as suggested, long polling should be all about that chat. If a person changed/edited a chat content, you simply push to the active connections a *message*, the receiving script should than update the content (only that one) inside the *View* (HTML). If every message inside a chat box has an UID should be that easy.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did a bit of research on calling SignalR and came across this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-high-frequency-realtime-with-signalr. As for getting the content, currently I have a class which returns different objects and then I have a bit of JavaScript code which appends according to what data I pass in, I will update my post to show how my project is setup.

Comment: The interval in the example is used as a throttle, though. It's there to *reduce* the amount of calls. By the looks of it, you should still be fine just calling the server when there is something to broadcast.